# Date fields in Dexterity custom view template - some not rendering

Tags: plone, dexterity

I have a dexterity content type with custom fields that I have added to the "metadata" tab under `portal_catalog`.

I have constructed my view template with the following (it is a modfication of `folder_listing`):

```
<td tal:content="item/date_request" />
<td tal:content="item/date_due_completed" />
<td tal:content="item/date_completed" />
<td tal:content="item/authorisation_required" />
<td tal:content="item/authorisation_acquired" />
<td tal:content="item/job_status" />
```

However when I view the folder_listing view I get the following output:

```
<td>2013-04-30</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>Yes</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<td>Incomplete</td>
```

The `item/date_due_completed` and `item/date_completed` don't seem to render anything, however the exact same information above for `item/date_request` renders just fine.

To test this I have modified the view for the content type itself and used `context/date_due_completed` and `context/date_completed` and it renders the information fine!

I am very confused as to why I am unable to render the first date field just fine on `folder_listing` and yet am unable to render the other two.

Has anyone experienced this in the past and is aware of what is going wrong?

**EDIT**

I have also tried indexing those fields and although in `portal_catalog` I can now see my content type being indexed for `date_due_completed` and `date_completed` the information contained within those fields do not appear on my `folder_listing` template.

**EDIT #2**

I have discovered that if you have multiple date fields, all indexed and metadata added, then refer to them in a view template (if the fields were entered with the same date) only one of them will display, is there a work-around to this?

Upon entering different values for each date field my output is as follows:

```
<td>2013-04-30</td>
<td>2013-05-30</td>
<td>2013-06-30</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<td>Incomplete</td>
```

Comment: Did you reindex existing objects after adding the metadata specification to the catalog?

Comment: I tried reindexing after I had added the metadata, I didn't seem to work at first so I just created a few more objects with my content type and it seemed to start working. I'm guessing it just took a while to index

Comment: The symptom for needing reindexing is that old content (created or last edited before the metadata field addition) lacks metadata in the catalog search results. New content would have the metadata. Does that match your experience?

Comment: @SteveM I believe the object I created using my custom content type lacked the metadata for those date fields, I then added the metadata and then edited the content type, added dates to the fields and saved my changes, do you think that would produce this problem? I'm guessing it doesn't reindex the object when you hit save like it does if I was to create a new one from scratch?

Comment: Content objects are indexed when saved and reindex when edited.